# Obviate the need to specify every folder for a manual setup

Tags: init-file, load-path, load

I run all my Emacs packages manually without any package manager. My setup is a simple `init.el` file with this kind of direction:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/packages/ace-window")

(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/packages/dired+")
    
(require 'ace-window)
(require 'dired+)
```

Is there a way simply to specify the `~/.emacs.d/packages/` directory without having to spell out all the folders in separate lines as above. I.e. simply point Emacs to treat all subfolders as packages.

Comment: Any reason why you're not just putting all of the elisp into one directory?

Comment: That's a good idea. I suppose it is because I have simply been cloning the packages from git.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
(defvar my-packages-dir "~/.emacs.d/packages")

(let ((default-directory my-packages-dir))
  (normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(defvar my-packages-directory "~/.emacs.d/packages")

(dolist (package-directory 
          (directory-files my-packages-directory :absolute))
  (add-to-list 'load-path package-directory))
```

Comment: This generated an error from Emacs: `Warning (initialization): Your ‘load-path’ seems to contain
your ‘.emacs.d’ directory: c:/red/.emacs.d/packages/..
This is likely to cause problems...
Consider using a subdirectory instead, e.g.: c:/red/.emacs.d/lisp`. The error persisted after I made a lips directory in `.emacs.d`, but went once I made a lisp directory off my home folder.

Comment: Do you have a subdirectory called "packages" into which you clone your various git-based packages? That is essential for this code to work.

Comment: @Fran Burstall's solution is better.